# Sumif with a moving sumrange

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have data, in corresponding columns right next to each other like : total in column n and hours in column o, I need a formula that changes my sumrange in my sumif formula.

how to change the referring column for the sum range in a sum if formula based on the column name being selected from a drop down list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the "offset" formula.

The sumif formula would look like this:

sumif(column range1, criteria, offset(column range2, , reference offset))

reference offset would be cell a1 and contain the number of columns you want the formula to move. So if a1 = 0. Your oringial column range2 would be the summed cells. If a1 is changed to = 1, the formula would sum one more column over, to column range2 + 1.

Comment: Thanks! How will I link that to a different sheet in the workbook?

Comment: Link what? The reference offset?

Comment: No never mind it works fine.  I just start from the corresponding column and depending how I want it to move, I can include the math in a logic formula. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to base the sum range on the column header in row 1 as per your question then perhaps use `INDEX/MATCH` like this

`=SUMIF(A:A,"x",INDEX(B:Z,0,MATCH("name",B1:Z1,0)))`

That will do a sumif for value "x" in col A with the sum range being the column with "name" in row 1